# Configure a printer to Laravel 5.6 project which generates a PDF and print the PDF

Tags: laravel

I have a project that I coded in Laravel 5.6 which generates pdf. I want that file to be printed automatically after it is generated. So is there any way to configure a printer to my laravel project?

Comment: mention your operating system have you installed the printer drivers on your operating system?

Comment: Yes i have, I'm using a windows 8.1

Comment: So whenever you give the print command in the code it automatically prints on the default printer of your hosted machine or Do you want anything else?

Comment: my code generates pdf i need print that file , Can do it with print commanda?

Comment: Yes, you can do with that just use windows.print or whatever available in laravel as i am not aware of laravel so search for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use html2pdf library.

Comment: but i can i print automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can't print directly from web server.
But you can run script from PHP to print the file. You should generate your pdf and save it somewhere, then run the script and send it to printer.
Example: `print c:\your_pdf_file.pdf /c /d:lpt1`
Check this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_printing.htm